# Getting error in dataframe typeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply this operation on my dataframe df:

```
df[df.a, 'b'] = df.c*df.b
```

where data types of a,b,c are:

```
a: bool
b: float64
c: float64
```

But I am getting the error `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Is it happening because of na value present in column b or c? If yes, is there a way to ignore the operation for na values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try use the `loc` accessor and it should be fine.

```
df.loc[df.a,'b']=df.c*df.b
```